# Lose style for "body" using outer CSS file

Tags: html, css, background, outer-join

I've tried to put my style for my HTML into outer file.
I've just created the file "mystyle.css" and put "style" code using copy-paste.
Then I've fill-in "head" by the next line:

```
<link href='.\css\mystyle.css' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>
```

That's all that I've done. As a result, styles are working, but...style for body is turned-off. It means I've lost my background and some global attributes...

Search in Internet haven't make any results. Please, help me to find the reason and correct a mistake.

[GitHub](https://github.com/Alex-Kalinin-jr/css-question)

Comment: When pointing to your background image, you first need to go 'up' 1 folder: ../

Answer (score 0):

Use this style for `body` element.

```
body {
    background-image: url(../bgmain.jpeg);
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-attachment: fixed;
    background-position: center center;
    background-size: cover;
    font-size: 100%;
}
```

**Note:**
In your code, `background-image` is set `url(./bgmain.jpeg)`, but in my code, it is set `url(../bgmain.jpeg)`.
The difference is that your code is looking for image in the `css` folder, but not found. 
And my code is looking for image in the root folder, so found the image.

Comment: I'm red of shame. Thanks a lot.